# Vuforia tracking works in Editor but not on Android Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using Unity 2018.2.17f1 and Vuforia Unity Extension Version 7.5.26 and build a App tracking an Cylindric Image Target. 
The tracking is working fine in Editor, however when I try to run it on my phone the tracking does not work.

When looking at the Log output of the phone I see: Vuforia initialization successful

and there are no errors and also no Message about any success of tracking ...

Anyone had a simmilar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may cause due to android versions. Newer API levels require runtime permissions. Grant camera permission and kill the app and then run the app, bit weird but it may work.